# GCP AI notebook instance permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a GCP AI notebook instance. Anyone with admin access to notebook in my project can open notebook and read, modify or delete any folder/file which is created by me or any other user in my team. Is there a way to create a private repository like /home/user, like we could've done if we used JupyterHub installed on a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably created a Notebook using Service Account mode. You can provide access to single users only  via single-user [mode](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_403_forbidden_error)

Example:

```
proxy-mode=mail,proxy-user-mail=user@domain.com
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.  
This is a customer environment, where they want only one instance. Would it be advisable to create multiple instances for each of the resources, and then combine the work in the master instance? Please suggest

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean combine the work in the master instance. What is work and what is a master instance? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- Implementing your requirement is not feasible with AI Notebooks. AI Notebooks is intended for a rapid prototyping and development environment that can be easily managed, and advanced multi-user scenarios fall outside its intended purpose.
- The Python Kernel in AI Notebooks always runs under the Linux user "Jupyter" regardless of what GCP user accesses the notebook. [Anyone who has editor permissions](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/create-new#determine_who_has_access_to_the_jupyterlab_instance) to your Google Cloud project can see each other's work through the Jupyter UI.
- In order to isolate the user's work, the recommended option is to set up individual notebook instances for each user. Please find the '**Single User**' [option](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#create-with-options).
- It’s not feasible to combine multiple instances to a master instance in AI Notebooks. So, the recommended ways to give each user a Notebook instance and share any source code via GIT or other repository system. Please find [Save a Notebook to GitHub](https://cloud.google.com/notebooks/docs/save-to-github) doc for more information.

Comment: yes we will have to go for the 3rd option as you pointed. Thanks!